# HairEyeColor bar plot in R

Tags: r

This is related to : [HairEyeColor bar chart in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394927/haireyecolor-bar-chart-in-r)

I am using following code to produce a similar plot:

```
mm = melt(HairEyeColor)                                                                                                             
ggplot(mm)+geom_bar(aes(x=Hair, y=value, fill=Eye), stat='identity',position='dodge')+facet_grid(Sex~.)
```

[image]

I want to have each bar show hair color in upper part and eye color in lower part. How can this be done? I tried to modify the code in previous question but could not manage. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is, I don't think this is a good visualization though...

```
mm2 <- mm
mm2$value <- mm2$value/4

ggplot(mm)+geom_bar(aes(x=Hair, y=value, fill=Eye), stat='identity',position='dodge')+facet_grid(Sex~.) +
  geom_bar(data = mm2, mapping = aes(x=Hair, y=value, fill=Hair, group=Eye), stat = "identity", position = "dodge", colour = "white") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = sub("blond", "yellow", sub("hazel", "gold", tolower(sort(unique(c(levels(mm$Eye), levels(mm$Hair))))))))
```

*UPDATE*

```
mm2 <- mm
mm2$value <- mm2$value/2

ggplot(mm)+geom_bar(aes(x=Hair, y=value, fill=Hair, group = Eye), stat='identity',position='dodge', colour = "white")+facet_grid(Sex~.) +
    geom_bar(data = mm2, mapping = aes(x=Hair, y=value, fill=Eye, group=Eye), stat = "identity", position = "dodge", colour = "white") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = sub("blond", "yellow", sub("hazel", "gold", tolower(sort(unique(c(levels(mm$Eye), levels(mm$Hair))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Good coding! But the hair color needs to be upper and eye color needs to be in lower part. Also both hair part and eye part of bar can be same (here upper part is much larger).